# can i pass std::ostream& to a function expecting std::ofstream

Tags: c++

What i'm trying to do is:
I want to redirect my error message erither to std::cerr or to a file
depending upon the `command-line` argument. If there is no log file provided then the program should output the error message on screen.
Here is my approach:

```
class A {

    void SetLogFileStream(T& err_outstream);
};
```

//main.cpp

```
A a;
std::string filename;
T1* t1;
if(argc>2) {
    filename = argv[1]; //if provided by command line 

    std::ofstream fp(filename);
    t1 = &fp;

}
else {

    std::ostream* err_outstream = &std::cerr;
    t1 = err_outstream;
}

a.SetLogFileStream(t1);
```

what should be the argument type of the function `SetLogFileStream` 
or the type `T1`
so that i can pass a pointer either to file or to  `std::cerr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the method as this:

```
class A {
    void SetLogStream(std::ostream& err_outstream);
};
```

There are several problems with your code. The file stream opened gets out of scope and is destroyed. You need to fix it like this:

```
std::ofstream f; // <-- this have to remain in scope while you use it for 'a'
A a;

if(args > 2) {
    f.open(argv[1]);
    a.SetLogStream(f);
} else {
    a.SetLogStream(cerr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. But the reverse is true.  You can pass an `std::ofstream` to a function expecting an `std::ostream&`, or an `std::ofstream*` to a function expecting an `std::ostream*`.  So your function should accept either an `std::ostream` ref or pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The type should be std::ostream. It woun't work exactly as you've coded it because your function parameter is a reference and your argument is a pointer. But fix that (either way) and it will work.